# Need to have an visualizer to show information from a file

Tags: c#, visualization, data-visualization, graph-visualization, visualizer

I am scanning a log file, the log file contains different component, component contain sub component & the sub component contains sub-sub component. There is parent child relationship with 3 levels.

The log files can be many and log file size goes round about 7MB.

Currently I am using nodeXL to represent the data in a graphical representation format.

For accomplishing this task, i am using C# Windows application with nodeXL.However I am not that satisfied with view & graphical display results of nodeXL for this case.

Need to have an attractive graphical display of the information I have.

Can anyone suggest any plugin tool or other way to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance

Note: I am not sure the #tag to put in for this question. Pls edit the #tag section as you find out appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/). I used it in a couple of projects now, mostly for debugging purposes. The format, in which you have to specify your graphs is really simple to write/generate. Furthermore you can modify the style of your nodes and edges as you like. The gallery on the provided website gives some examples. (google images for "graphviz examples" and you will see whats possible)